# Python wrapper that iterates over a list of classes

Tags: python, class

I am using a well-developed Python class (let's call it `Foo1D`) that has a bunch of great methods but only works on 1D data. Forking the repo and modifying every method to handle 2D data is prohibitively time consuming.

So, I'd like to make a "vectorized" wrapper `Foo2D` that accepts uncorrelated 2D input, converts it into a collection of `Foo1D` objects, iterates over the collection when a method is called, and returns an array of the results.

Here's what I've tried:

```
class Foo1D(object):    
    def __init__(self, data1D):
        self.offset = 20
        self.data = data1D+self.offset

    def multiply(self, x):
        return self.data*x

    def add(self, a):
        return self.data+a

class Foo2D(object):
    def __init__(self, data2D):
        dummy = Foo1D(data2D[0])
        self.__class__ = type(dummy.__class__.__name__, (self.__class__, dummy.__class__), {})
        self.__dict__ = dummy.__dict__
        del dummy

        self.data2D = [Foo1D(data1D) for data1D in data2D]

    def __getattr__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        result = [getattr(data1D, item)(*args, **kwargs) for data1D in self.data2D]

        return np.array(result)
```

This creates the `Foo1D` and `Foo2D` objects with the correct attributes but the `Foo2D` methods don't behave as expected. An example:

```
a1D = np.arange(10)
a2D = a1D.reshape(2,5)
A = Foo1D(a1D)
B = Foo2D(a2D)
```

So when I run `A.multiply(2)` I get `array([40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58])` as expected.

But when I run `B.multiply(2)` I get `array([40, 42, 44, 46, 48])` when I expect to get `array([[40, 42, 44, 46, 48],[50, 52, 54, 56, 58]])`. This is because `B.data` is only the first element of `a2D` but I don't understand why.

Indeed if I do `np.array([getattr(i, 'multiply')(2) for i in B.data2D])` I get the answer I expect `array([[40, 42, 44, 46, 48],[50, 52, 54, 56, 58]])`.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your code doesn't work:

1. You want to use `__getattribute__` not `__getattr__`. In fact `Foo2D.__getattr__` never gets called (try putting a print statement in there).
2. If you fixed point 1 then `__getattribute__` would throw the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` because `self.data2D` is equivalent to `self.__getattribute__('data2D')`.
3. I think `Foo2D.multiply` is set by `self.__class__ = type(dummy.__class__.__name__, (self.__class__, dummy.__class__), {})`, so your only getting `Foo2D.data2D[0].multiply`. I'm willing to bet this line has other unintended consequences.
4. Only `self` and the attribute name are passed to `Foo2D.__getattribute__`. If `Foo2D.__getattr__` returns a function then this function handles the other arguments (e.g. `*args, **kwargs`).

Below I have implemented a version of `Foo2D` that I believe gives the desired effect. `Foo2D.__getattribute__` tries to use `object.__getattribute__` and only does something special if that throws an `AttributeError` (i.e. that attribute has not been set). If the requested attribute in `Foo1D` is callable (i.e. a function) then `Foo2D._vec_attr` is used to do the element-wise evaluation. Otherwise it just gives a vector of the attributes.

For Python2:

```
class Foo2D(object):
    def __init__(self, data2D):
        self.data2D = [Foo1D(data1D) for data1D in data2D]

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super(Foo2D, self).__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            if callable(getattr(self.data2D[0], attr)):
                return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._vec_attr(attr, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return np.array([getattr(data1D, attr) for data1D in self.data2D])

    def _vec_attr(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array([getattr(data1D, attr)(*args, **kwargs) for data1D in self.data2D])
```

For Python3:

```
class Foo2D(object):
    def __init__(self, data2D):
        self.data2D = [Foo1D(data1D) for data1D in data2D]

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            if callable(getattr(self.data2D[0], attr)):
                return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._vec_attr(attr, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return np.array([getattr(data1D, attr) for data1D in self.data2D])

    def _vec_attr(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        return np.array([getattr(data1D, attr)(*args, **kwargs) for data1D in self.data2D])
```

The difference is in the call to `super`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much.

Comment: I was getting `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` when I call certain methods so I changed line 7 to just `return super().__getattribute__(attr)` and it works like a charm now. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yes. This is a Python 2 vs 3 issue. My code is written for Python 2 and you're running Python 3. I should get with the times.